# MVC Pattern with ARC

Tags: iphone, ios, model-view-controller, automatic-ref-counting

As a newcomer to iOS, I found that ARC has thus far really helped with rapid development. That being said, there are a few caveats where I am unsure how ARC fits and with previous longstanding iOS patterns, such as MVC. Here's how I'm trying to picture things, and any clarification or corrections in my understanding would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using Storyboard to instantiate and setup some view controllers for my app. From the docs I've read, when the active view controller segues to a different view controller, the sending view controllers instance variables are lost (yes?/no?). As such, I'm using a model layer to store data for the app. Now here wheres my understanding starts to get (more) fuzzy..

Say I have a model data object in use by only one view controller. I allocate and instantiate the data object from within the view controller (in viewDidLoad). So now I have a reference to the data object from within my controller and while the controller is in the foreground, can freely coordinate information from views, to the controller, possibly to the data object, back to the controller to update the views using the MVC pattern. OK, cool..

But when I segue to a different view controller, the sender controller's instance variables are lost and thus the only reference to the data object is lost. Does ARC then automatically release the data object too?

My goal is to be able to save data for a particular view controller so that when I return to it I can update it with the saved state. How is this done with MVC and ARC in iOS? Options I've thought of (remember, I'm new lol)

1. Include a reference to the data object in the Application Delegate. It's not going anywhere so the reference to the data object won't either. Is this good precise?
2. Store all data in static form in the data class object?
3. Use NSUserDefaults

Any advice would be greatly appreciated going forward. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using, for example, a push or modal segue, the view controller of the previous view is *not* released. If you ever receive a `didReceiveMemoryWarning`, the view, itself might be released, but the controller will not. You controller's ivars will be preserved, so when the secondary view controller is popped off (or dismissed), your original ivars will be as they were before.

Comment: You told "If you're using, for example, a push or modal segue, the view controller of the previous view is not released", then on using which segue view controller will get released?

Comment: I'm using a custom segue with the following overridden perform method (I don't like all the transition animations)
- (void) perform {   
    [[self sourceViewController] presentModalViewController:    
        [self destinationViewController] animated:NO];
}

Comment: Then you're fine. That's a custom segue that is doing a modal transition (which preserves the old controller).

Comment: If, for example, you were using a split view controller for the iPad and you use the replace segue to replace the detail view controller with another, I don't imagine that this would save the old detail controller (so you'd want to save its model's information elsewhere, if you made any changes to it).

Comment: BTW, if you're supporting pre iOS 5, feel free to use the deprecated presentModalViewController, but if not, you might want to use presentViewController.

Comment: I mean, I would be really happy if this is the case as I originally assumed this during the overall design of the app, but I swear every time I leave and return to a controller the properties are reset. Properties are just ivars with compiler synthesized getter/setters are they not?

Comment: @Zak - How are you returning to the previous controller? If its with another segue, this _will_ create a new view controller. You have to dismiss the presented controller instead.

Comment: @Zak How are you getting back to your original view controller? Are you invoking dismissViewControllerAnimated (or dismissModalViewControllerAnimated if you're pre iOS 5)? This is the correct way to get back. Or are are you doing another segue back to the original view controller? If so, you're erroneously creating another view controller. Alternatively, are you setting your properties anywhere like in viewWillAppear or something like that?

Comment: @jrturton, Robert Ryan. There's the problem. Had no idea a segue _creates_ a new view controller and that I'd need to dismiss the presented controller. After reading through so much of the Apple docs at once I miss some of these crucial points. Thanks a ton guys this was really driving me crazy.

Comment: If I had the ability to do the 1 up thing I would :)

Comment: @RobertRyan - snap on the comments!

Comment: Follow Up Question: What if I had multiple VC's, each of which I'd like to keep track of its own ivars. I'd like to switch around between the VC's freely (possibly looping ie. VC1 -> VC2 -> VC3 -> VC1 -> VC3 ...). It seems using segue's wouldn't be appropriate, neither would manually presenting one VC from another. Thoughts?

Comment: I don't know what UI you're looking for, but usually this sort of free navigation between a bunch of view controllers is done via something like a UITabBarController (so the user has clear tab buttons at the bottom of the screen to pick which view controller they want to navigate to). Does this work for you, or would you like your own navigation between these three views?

Comment: @Zak If you don't like the tab bar, iOS 5 also offers the ability to create your own container view controller. See [WWDC 2011 session 102](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102) for a detailed discussion of view controller containment. Or see the [UIViewController documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW81) on view controller containment. This is all more complicated than just using an existing container (like the tab bar), but it's an option.

Comment: There are other options, too, e.g. programmatically created views that your container transitions in and out, but I won't go into that unless you say that the elegant tab bar doesn't do the job for you.

Comment: @Zak one final point. Others may point out that you can technically load another view controller's view and transition your current view to that view (and if you're careful, that can work), but that WWDC video I reference above talks about the problems with that and why you should use view controller containment. In short, see if the tab view does it for you, and if not we can start a chat to discuss the other options.

Comment: @RobertRyan. Thanks for the advice - much, much appreciated. The UI I'm building is a part of a game where a view controller is responsible for different UI's presented during a given game state, ie. playing, main menu, options, pause, highscore ect. In the future I don't think I'll go this route, but for my first app I though I'd keep it really simple. 
It seems like using storyboard might have been a bad decision and that I ought to go with using a view controller container to load view controllers in and out from nib files.
The other option would be to have a separate data object to keep

Comment: track of all the games data, then just update a given view controller when its presented modally (through a segue?).
As per norm, any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks for taking some time to help out.

Comment: @Zak I hear you, but I think you'll find that the simple push/present segue model will work fine (if you look at it, it's what most games do ... if you have "high scores" on the main menu, is it important to be able to get there from the options screen, too, or is it ok to go back to the main menu?; and just because you have a push/modal segue from main menu to options doesn't mean that you can't also have a simular segue from the pause screen to options). You can have a pretty dynamic feel with the simple push/modal segues.

Comment: @RobertRyan In my original design you could reach states in a number of different ways. In some cases, like the 'options' state, can be reached by either the 'main menu' or 'paused' states. For simple modal segue's this is fine because you can just dismiss the 'options' state to go back to previous state. However, in some cases its not as straight forward. ex. 'main menu' -> 'playing' -> 'pause' -> 'main menu'. If I use the main menu VC as the VC presenting all the others, this is still relatively easy as I can just dismiss the 'playing' VC from the 'pause' state and arrive back at 'main menu'

Comment: The problem I was finding with this approach is that since I would be segueing to the 'playing' state from the main menu every time, it would reset the ivars of the playing VC.

Comment: I want to invite you to chat (to get this out of the comments), but you need a few more reputation points before I can do that. Hopefully someone else will thumbs up your original question so you get enough reputation points so we can move this to chat. Too complicated to continue this via comments.

Comment: Since we can't chat, I'll answer you here. 1. I'd suggest you do _not_ have a segue from pause to main menu. Just have segues from pause to options and pause to high scores, but that's it. 2. Maybe your pause screen also has a quit option that returns you to the main menu by popToRootViewController (assuming you've been pushing). So perhaps you have something like: http://www.robertmryan.com/images/SO/11137602.png

Comment: @RobertRyan you're a Godsend. That's almost exactly what I have. You'd recommend pushing?

Comment: @Zak I like pushing, because you then have the option of popToRootViewController (which might be useful to have if someone taps on "quit game" from the pause menu ... you could pop all the way back to the main menu). You also get the built in functionality of the back button in the navigation bar, if you want it (just hide the navigation bar if you don't want it). Maybe the nav bar would be distracting during the game, but it might be ok on pause, options, and high score screens. It's an aesthetic/design decision.

Comment: @RobertRyan Hey just got back from a little trip there Rob. Didn't have chance to thank you again before I left. Greatly appreciate you spending time to help out the community. Regards